# Entity Framework 6.3 with ASP.NET Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

How do I would use Entity Framework 6.3 with ASP .NET Core 3? Specifically, I wish to generate a model from an existing database. It does not appear that I can add an Entity Data Model unless I target the full .NET Framework (however, isn't Entity Framework 6.3 supported on .NET Core 3?)

Comment: Morning, welcome to stack, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This article will help you [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-6-3-preview-with-net-core-support/).

Comment: Thanks Pedro - I've seen that article. It's for a preview edition and describes only code-first - not database first

Comment: @Muaddib878 you aren't asking about database first, you're asking about EDMX. first Even in EF 6.2, EDMX is *not* a recommended solution -  it hasn't been for years. Code first and reverse engineering a database were added because EDMX was too cumbersome - every time you modified the database you'd have to update *two* models. Even if you started from the EDMX designer, you'd still have one more model to modify yourself. I'm using database first all the time - with code. I design the database then update my classes.

Comment: @Muaddib878 given that, adding EDMX support to .NET Core has a low priority, and is primarily a Visual Studio issue

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  I can't really find any resources on using EF 6+ Database-first without using EDMX.   Now, if you are talking about Entity Framework Core - that it is entirely different and I may go that route eventually.

Comment: @Panagiotis   Can you cite sources discouraging EDMX in an EF 6+ database-first approach?   After making changes to the the database;  update the model and it appropriately generates classes, DBSSets and creates the mapping. It's great in that it will entitize db functions for data retrieval (scalar and table-value - very useful) and even stored procs.

Comment: @Muaddib878 do you want the links to all the Microsoft blog posts, MSDN Magazine articles going back 4 years? Or how both C# and SQL Server MVPs reacted to the double models when EF was first introduced? It wasn't nice, and yes, I was there (I was a SQL Server MVP back then). None of the features you describe need EDMX at all. A *single* mapping is enough, the way it's done now in code.

Comment: EDMX's double mapping on the other hand (class to EDMX, EDMX to database) was supposed to be more flexible and allow the same model to work with different classes and different databases but that was probably only 1% of applications - and I'm probably being generous. For everyone else the intermediate model simply meant we had to edit mappings twice. In most cases one of the mappings is identical to either the object or the database model, so what's the point of the EDMX model? It's definitely not an *Domain Entity* model, those live at a higher level

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos    Can you at least cite a few sources?  Regarding your statement "A single mapping is enough, the way it's done now in code".  I can see how this is done with Entity Framework Core.  But with Entity Framework 6 - I'm not sure how the mapping would be accomplished w/o EDMX.  Are you referring to using code first Migrations?

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos.  I don't have a problem with EDMX and never had to run into a situation where I had to "edit the model twice".   However, I found an answer to my own question for anyone interested - here's how to map to an existing database in EF 6 w/o EDMX:    https://cpratt.co/entity-framework-code-first-with-existing-database/.  I will need to see if db table-valued function can be mapped in this manner as well (one of the reasons I found using EDMX useful)

Comment: @Muaddib878 that's not what that article shows - it doesn't create the model, it only shows how to use a connection string by name. Athanasios's answer shows how to actually create the model in code

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos Excuse me? The article describes that you can create your classes in code for your model; map them to database tables; add your dbsets; and yes - specify your connection string in code. The article even mentions tools that can auto generate classes for your model. Do you have additional information, or do you wish to keep pontificating? Athanasios's solution is for Entity Framework *Core* not Entity Framework 6.....

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to generate the model from the tables of your database, using .Net Core with Entity Framework.

You can do this by using Entity Framework Core and Tools packages in your project.

```
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
  dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

And the [dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet)

Example:

```
    dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=Blogging;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Per the designer support for EF 6.3, I think you are out of luck:

This is the recommended approach from Microsoft at the moment:

> How to work with EDMX files in .NET Core projects
>   On the tooling side, we plan to release an updated EF6 designer in an upcoming update of Visual Studio 2019 which will work with projects that target .NET Core (tracked in issue #883).
>
> Until this new version of the designer is available, we recommend that you work with your EDMX files inside projects that target .NET Framework. You can then add the EDMX file and the generated classes for the entities and the DbContext to the .NET Core 3.0 or .NET Standard 2.1 project as linked files.

https://github.com/efcore/EdmxDotNetCoreSample/

Comment: I didn't realize the question at first, sorry. If you want ot keep track, check https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/1053 where there is a request for a tool like dotnet ef but has not materialized yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Visual Studio to reverse-engineer EF6 code-first models from a database, but I don't believe it's enabled by default in a .NET Core project. However, you *can* generate the models in a .NET Framework project and either copy the files or convert the project to .NET Core later.

If you have the Entity Framework 6 Tools component installed in Visual Studio, then from a .NET Framework project you should be able to `Add -> New Item -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model`. This kicks off a wizard to choose which tables should have models generated.

(I think this has been around since at least VS 2017 - I assume we're using VS 2019 because of EF 6.3 / .NET Core 3.0.)